# Best Practice with accessing API Server on mobile app which login using OAuth

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, api-design

I have the following entities:

- An mobile app
- in-house API Server
- in-house OAuth Server

I need to **implement OAuth in mobile app to the OAuth Server**, and **access user information in the API server afterward**, and I am having trouble with how this can be achieved securely. I have only think of the following methods:

#### Method 1: Pass user id directly from Mobile App to API server

1. Login user through OAuth in mobile app (using library like AppAuth)
2. Store the user id retrived from OAuth in mobile app
3. Mobile app send the user id to the API server, so they can retrive the correct resources back to the mobile app

However, this method seems non-secure, **as attacker can fake their user id** when passing to the API.

#### Method 2: Pass OAuth access_token to API server, let API server call OAuth server again

1. Login user through OAuth in mobile app (using library like AppAuth)
2. Store the access_token retrived from OAuth
3. Mobile app send the access_token  to the API server
4. API server pass the access_token  to the OAuth server
5. OAuth server return the user info back to API server
6. Now API server have the user info, and can return the correct resources back to the mobile app
   [image]
   Method 2 seems more secure, however I don't seems to see this kind of infrastructure suggested by anybody. This method also seems resource intensive as API server need to call OAuth server every time an API is called.

So my question is:

1. What is the best Practice with accessing API Server on mobile app which login using OAuth?
2. If there is a best practice, any link to those resources?

Thank you!